# Is it safe to call timer_pending() before init_timer()?

Tags: c, linux, timer, module, kernel

It seems sensible to wrap a call to del_timer() or del_timer_sync() within an if() statement, such as:

```
if (timer_pending(&t))
{
    del_timer_sync(&t);
}
```

but can I safely do that in the case where we may not yet have done our init_timer() call on struct t? Do I need to jump through hoops doing something like this instead?

```
init_timer(&t);
t.function = foo;
.
.
.
if (t.function && timer_pending(&t)) ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt it.

Here's the code ([timer.h#L169](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/timer.h#L169)) for `timer_pending`:

```
static inline int timer_pending(const struct timer_list * timer) {
     return timer->entry.next != NULL;
}
```

And here's the code ([timer.c#L621](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/kernel/timer.c#L621)) that ends up initializing the timer when you call `init_timer`:

```
static void do_init_timer(struct timer_list *timer, unsigned int flags,
                          const char *name, struct lock_class_key *key)
{
        struct tvec_base *base = __raw_get_cpu_var(tvec_bases);

        timer->entry.next = NULL;
        timer->base = (void *)((unsigned long)base | flags);
        timer->slack = -1;
#ifdef CONFIG_TIMER_STATS
        timer->start_site = NULL;
        timer->start_pid = -1;
        memset(timer->start_comm, 0, TASK_COMM_LEN);
#endif
        lockdep_init_map(&timer->lockdep_map, name, key, 0);
}
```

Note that `timer_pending` is checking `entry.next` which is not initialized until you call `init_timer`.  So `timer_pending` may return true when the timer has not been initialized.

I don't know what the effect may be of callingn `del_timer_sync` on a timer which has not been initialized, though.

Comment: Thanks. I suspected this was the case. The problem is that I want to have module cleanup code that removes the timer, but only if it was ever set. I reckon using the 'function' member of the struct will probably be my safest test then (or just call init_timer on any timer structs in the module init code, irrespective of whether the timer is going to end up being used).

Comment: OK, I think I've arrived at my final answer: do the init_timer() call for any timer structs *both* at module init *and* for a given struct immediately after any del_timer() or del_timer_sync() call to ensure that anywhere later that we might do a timer_pending(), timer_del() or similar, we won't explode in a heap.

Comment: According to the kernel documentation, you must call init_timer before *any* of the other operations... 
https://www.kernel.org/doc/htmldocs/device-drivers/API-init-timer-key.html

Answer (score 0):

[del_timer](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/kernel/timer.c#L959)() does the timer_pending() check internally, you don't have to.

You **must** however have called init_timer() before calling del_timer. (After all, if you don't it'll just contain garbage).

So this is enough:

```
init_timer(&t);
del_timer(&t);
```